# How to not have to type self in init when subclassing

Tags: python, python-3.x, typechecking, mypy

MCVE:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, num: int):
        self.value = num

class B(A):
    def __init__(self): # Mypy: function is missing a type annotation
        A.__init__(self, 7) # Mypy: Expression has type "Any"
```

I would like Mypy to not force me to have to type `self`. It seems obvious to me what the type of `self` is, and Mypy is able to figure it out for `A`, so why not `B`?

How can I define `B` such that I'm not forced to do the following?

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, num: int):
        self.value = num

class B(A):
    def __init__(self: 'B'):
        A.__init__(self, 7)
```

Comment: Note, please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions

Comment: How are you running `mypy` (and what version are you using)? `mypy tmp.py` doesn't report anything.

Comment: mypy linter in Atom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to annotate the return type of your signature:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
```

Mypy will let you omit the return type on specifically the constructor if one or more other arguments are annotated, but you'll need to include it on no-argument constructors.

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3358#issuecomment-465783430) by Guido confirms this.